# edit crontab on server programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, bash, ssh, debian

I'm developing an iOS-App which should be able to run some bash scripts on a remote server (debian) at a regular basis. 
My idea is to create the script on the remote host and add a cronjob via a simple SSH line which I found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/296949/programmatically-add-entry-to-users-crontab) which runs the script, so the job is independent of the iOS-Device.

```
(crontab -u USERNAME -l ; echo "line to be added") | crontab -u USERNAME -
```

Moreover the App should be able to stop/edit/remove these scripts if necessary.
The steps I don't know and couldn't figure out yet, is:

1. How to programmatically create the script on the remote host, so it can be executed by the cronjob
2. How to edit or remove code lines programmatically, which are anywhere in another script (f.ex. */etc/crontab*).

I am thankful for every other approach too.

Comment: What kind of server are we talking about here? Is this any UNIX server that the user has access to, or is it a specific server used by your application?

Comment: To be exactly it is a RaspberryPi with Raspbian installed, hosted by the user